# when i type in first name label it also writes inside last name label

Tags: json, reactjs, web-frontend

I just created a simple first name and last name labels with a submit button. The problem is when I write inside the first name label it also write in last name label. Why is this the case?

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import App from "./components/app";
import reducers from "./reducers";

class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: "" };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChanges.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  }

  handleChanges(event) {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert("A name was submitted: " + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.value}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
        </label>
        <label>
          LastName:
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.value}
            onChange={this.handleChanges}
          />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<NameForm />, document.querySelector(".container"));
```

Comment: Both your inputs take the value from `this.state.value`. So if you edit one input the other will get the same value on re-render. A re-render happens every time `setState()` gets called.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are saving the values of the input fields in the same variable, this.state.values.
You should try saving them separately, this.state.firstName / this.state.lastname

Answer (score 1):

That's because you only have a single `value` representing your first name and last name.

You could have two separate state variables instead, one for each.

**Example**

```
class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { firstName: "", lastName: "" };

    this.handleFirstNameChange = this.handleFirstNameChange.bind(this);
    this.handleLastNameChange = this.handleLastNameChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleFirstNameChange(event) {
    this.setState({ firstName: event.target.value });
  }

  handleLastNameChange(event) {
    this.setState({ lastName: event.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("A name was submitted: ", this.state.firstName, this.state.lastName);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.firstName}
            onChange={this.handleFirstNameChange}
          />
        </label>
        <label>
          LastName:
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.lastName}
            onChange={this.handleLastNameChange}
          />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There must be different state variables for each input field but in your case you just created value state variable

```
    this.state = { value: "" };
```

which is representing the value of each input label.